# Error on comparison of numbers from textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 textboxes which inputs 2 values from the user and compares the first value with the second. If the first value is less than the second value, it enters the loop where the user has to input the values again.

The problem I am getting is if I input 10 and 9.9 in the text boxes, it is entering into the loop and saying that 10 is less than 9.9. This happens only with 10,100 and 1000. Please help.

I even tried defining Long type variables for both the integers and assigned them and compared them, excel just hangs. Please help

Here is the code below.

```
    If Mean < LSLValue Then
            MsgBox "Please enter a numeric value greater than LSL as Nominal Value"
            Me.DimnTxt.Value = InputBox("Enter the Nominal")
            Me.LSLTxt.Value = InputBox("Enter the LSL")
            Mean = Me.DimnTxt.Value
            LSLValue = Me.LSLTxt.Value
End If
Loop Until Mean >= LSLValue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be because you are comparing text instead of number.
Try convert to number then compare. EG:

```
if CDbl(Textbox1.value) < CDbl(Textbox2.value)  then
'....
end if
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working fine now. I tried using cdec but it didnot seem to work. Thank you